# Can someone help me to understand the binary output of the getRGB() method?

Tags: java, rgb, pixel

I am learning java and I am trying to get the RGB information from a pixel. I managed to do so, however, I would like to understand the reason why when I print out the original getRGB() value, I get an incomplete binary number with a minus sign:

```
-100110011001100110011010
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MyImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage img = null;
        File f = null;

        try {
            f = new File("D:\\preview.jpg");
            img = ImageIO.read(f);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        int p = img.getRGB(0, 0);
        int a = (p >> 24) & 0xff;
        int r = p >> 16 & 0xff;
        int g = p >> 8 & 0xff;
        int b = p & 0xff;
        System.out.println(a + "      " + r + "     " + g + "     " + b);
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(a, 2) + " " + Integer.toString(r, 2) + " " + Integer.toString(g, 2) + " "
                + Integer.toString(b, 2));
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(p, 2)); // why this number?

        }
}
```

Output:

```
255      102     102     102
11111111 1100110 1100110 1100110
-100110011001100110011010
```

Comment: If you want it to be more human readable, you could call `Integer.toHexString(...)` on the RGB value

Comment: Hi Lance, thank you, your advice helped me to understand that my confusion was caused by fact I used `Integer.toString()` instead of `Integer.toHexString()` or `Integer.toBinaryString()` to visualize the `getRGB()` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 8 bits for Alpha, Red, Blue, and Green each. The value can be negative if the first bit in the integer is set. This is because 4 different values are packed into a single integer variable. Normally the first bit determines if the value is negative (2's complement).

```
-100110011001100110011010 //
```

> Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB colorspace. Color conversion takes place if this default model does not match the image ColorModel. There are only 8-bits of precision for each color component in the returned data when using this method.

[BufferedImage.getRGB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int))